# Polling Windows native window events in a separate thread

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I need a Windows native window handle for a renderer, but I'm struggling to poll events correctly.

First, I create a window, which works fine on its own:

```cpp
WNDPROC Window::MakeWindow( LPCWSTR _title, unsigned int _width, unsigned int _height ) {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    HWND hwnd;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    m_WindowClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    m_WindowClass.style         = 0;
    m_WindowClass.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    m_WindowClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    m_WindowClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    m_WindowClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
    m_WindowClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    m_WindowClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    m_WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    m_WindowClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    m_WindowClass.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)g_szClassName;
    m_WindowClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&m_WindowClass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        (LPCWSTR)g_szClassName,                     // Window class
        _title,    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        _width, _height,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    PollEvents();

    return NULL;
}
```

After creating the window, I want to check for user inputs. In the code snippets I copied, they did it like this:

```cpp
void PollEvents() {
    MSG Msg;

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
}
```

But, since this blocks my code, I tried using a separate thread to do this. So, at the end of my window creation, I create a thread like so:

```cpp
m_PollThread = new std::thread(PollEvents);
```

To test if it's working, I wrote this `main()` function:

```cpp
int main() {
    // poll thread is created here
    Window* window = new Window( "Test Window", 1024, 720 );

    while (true) {
        Sleep(10);
    };

    // poll thread is closed/awaited here
    delete window;
}
```

But, the window ends up frozen, so just the `while` loop is executed while the other thread seems to do nothing.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: okay sorry, i'll fix it right away

Comment: where is, in this code, your thread that calls PollEvents?

Comment: Why separate thread for Windows events and not for the other work?

Comment: @i486 Is that the reason why it doesn't work? Because it can't access the window in another thread?

Comment: @Federico at the end of the window creation. Just replace the `PollEvents()` with `m_PollThread = new std::thread( PollEvents);`

Comment: Windows windows are tied to threads. When you call GetMessage you get messages for the current thread's windows and not any other thread's windows.

Comment: @user253751 But how do windowing libs like glfw handle this then? Do they create a window in a separate thread and communicate between the threads somehow?

Comment: @noergel1 you have to call glfwPollEvents or something like that, and it calls GetMessage inside it. (Actually it probably calls PeekMessage)

Comment: @noergel1 Search for info how to access Win32 GUI from other thread.

Comment: Instead of moving the event handling off the main thread, move the renderer (the one in "I need a Windows native window handle for a renderer") off the main thread.

Comment: Your *PollEvents* thread doesn't have a thread-specific message queue. [*To avoid the overhead of creating a message queue for non–GUI threads, all threads are created initially without a message queue. The system creates a thread-specific message queue only when the thread makes its first call to one of the specific user functions; no GUI function calls result in the creation of a message queue*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the thread that creates a window can receive messages for that window.  You cannot create a window in one thread and then receive messages for that window in another thread.

`GetMessage()` blocks until it receives a message, so your code freezes because you are calling `GetMessage()` in a thread that has no window to receive messages for, and the thread that created the window is not processing any messages for that window.

So, if you want to poll events periodically, in the creating thread, without blocking your code, use `PeekMessage()` instead of `GetMessage()`, eg:

```
void PollEvents() {
    MSG Msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to move **both** the window creation and the event loop into your worker thread.